# How to implement a custom 'confirm' prompt in JS using promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

This is the base code

```
$(".add-item").click(function() {
  var flag;
  var ask_about_flag = // some logic ... 
  if (ask_about_flag == true) {
    if (confirm("Add with a flag?") == true) {
      flag = true
    } else {
      flag = false
    }
  } 
  addItem(flag)
})
```

What I want to do though, is build a robust modal containing specific instructions about how to answer the 'Add with a flag?' question being posed. Within the modal, there will be 2 button elements for 'Yes' vs 'No'. So think of this as a basic modal (using Bootstrap):

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="flag_modal" aria-hidden="true" id="flag_modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h2 class="modal-title serif text-center">
            Add with a flag?
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <!-- detailed instructions -->
          <button id="yes" class="btn btn-lg">Yes</button>
          <button id="no" class="btn btn-lg">No</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Like the default `confirm` alert, the UX is that when `add-item` is clicked, if the not-included logic calculates that `ask_about_flag` is true, this modal pops up, and the code doesn't proceed to call `addItem` until user selects either `#yes` or `#no` to set the value of the flag.

However, it's also possible that upon `add-item` click, the not-included logic calculates that `ask_about_flag` is false, so the modal doesn't show and `addItem` is called (`flag = null` in this case).

Because of this, I think it makes sense for code organizing to keep `addItem` function call within the `add-item` click, rather than push it down into the button handlers (to be clear code below would work)

```
$(".add-item").click(function() {
  var ask_about_flag = // some logic ... 
  if (ask_about_flag == true) {
    $("#flag_modal").show()
  } 
  addItem()
})

$("#yes").click(function() {
  addItem(true)
})

$("#no").click(function() {
  addItem(false)
})
```

I want to do something instead like:

```
$(".add-item").click(function() {
  var flag;
  var ask_about_flag = // some logic ... 
  if (ask_about_flag == true) {
    // pop up modal to ask user to set value of flag
  } 
  // wait to execute until value of flag is set, if needed
  addItem(flag)
})
```

Seems like `Promises` are the way (let me know if not!), but that's still pretty new to me, so I took a stab with the below. Working up until when I click a `yes` or `no` button where I get `Uncaught TypeError: promise.resolve is not a function`

```
var promise; // declare so that it's available both from within `add-item` and `button` handlers

$(".add-item").click(function() {
  promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    var ask_about_flag = // some logic ... 
    if (ask_about_flag == true) {
      $("#flag_modal").modal("show")
    } else {
      resolve(null)
    }
  })

  promise.then(function(flag) {
    // flag is the parameter passed to resolve
    addItem(flag)
  })
})

$("#yes").click(function() {
  promise.resolve(true)
})

$("#no").click(function() {
  promise.resolve(false)
})
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/0g76ce5s/

Comment: Could you please make a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? There is code snippet button in SO.

Comment: You need to make another function with logic for Yes, no button when press, and add on html button `onClick="$("#flag_modal").modal("show")"`, then on that functions with yes or no trigger click, do your logic and on final function add `$("#flag_modal").modal("hide")` if you want

Comment: @ikhvjs here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0g76ce5s/

Comment: @BoBiTza your answer leaves out the `add-item` click handler entirely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I prefer your first approach as it is more separation of concerns.

However if you want to do the Promise approach, what you need to pass is the `resolve` function instead of the Promise.

Example below:

```js
var resolveGlobal; // declare so that it's available both from within `add-item` and `button` handlers

$(".add-item").click(function () {
    promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var ask_about_flag = true;
        if (ask_about_flag) {
            $("#flag_modal").modal("show");
            resolveGlobal = resolve;
        } else {
            resolve(null);
        }
    });

    promise.then(function (flag) {
        // flag is the parameter passed to resolve
        addItem(flag);
    });
});

$("#yes").click(function () {
    resolveGlobal(true);
});

$("#no").click(function () {
    resolveGlobal(false);
});

function addItem(flag) {
    console.log(flag);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <script
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <script
            src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="box">
            <div
                class="modal fade"
                tabindex="-1"
                role="dialog"
                aria-labelledby="flag_modal"
                aria-hidden="true"
                id="flag_modal"
            >
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h2 class="modal-title serif text-center">
                                Add with a flag?
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <!-- detailed instructions -->
                            <button id="yes" class="btn btn-lg">Yes</button>
                            <button id="no" class="btn btn-lg">No</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <button class="add-item">Add item</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks will try it ! also curious @ikhvjs maybe i just don't see it... why do you specifically think the first approach is more separation of concerns oriented?

Comment: @james, I think the first approach clearly show that each handler only do their job without dependencies to each other. So, once you change the additem click handler, you don’t need to change the yes/no click handler. 
However, for your promise approach, yes/no handler depends on the additem handler. For the first impression, first approach is more clearer than the promise one for me. Anyway, people have different idea and you may just choose the one you like.

Comment: ah ok from that perspective it does make sense. i think the dependency in my case is preferable because there's a lot more code going on that i didn't copy and i want to keep `addItem` with the handler so people aren't searching through the code for it, thanks!

Comment: @james, I see. Anyway, would accept this answer if you think it helps?

Answer (score 2):

I like @ikhvjs answer.

And it can be adapted to vanilla javascript quite easy.

```js
document.getElementById('addItem').onclick = function() {
  const dialog = document.getElementById('confirmDialog');
  promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    dialog.showModal();
    dialog.onclose = resolve;
  });
  promise.then(function(response) {
    alert(response.target.returnValue);
  });
};
```

```html
<dialog id="confirmDialog">
  <form method="dialog">
    <p>Add the item?</p>
    <button value="ok">Ok</button>
    <button value="cancel">No</button>
  </form>
</dialog>

<button id="addItem">Add item</button>
```